# Mule IDE unable to generate JAX-WS client

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, mule

Using Mule IDE version 3.2.3 to invoke JAX-WS web service. In the "Import WSDL" dialogue after entering the WSDL URL and package name the JAX-WS client generation fails with error message

```
Error generating from WSDL: Thrown by JAXB : A class/interface with same name is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
```

How do I specify jaxb customization in Mule IDE?

[image: Mule IDE Import WSDL]
[image: Mule IDE JAXB error]

Answer (score 0):

What you are covering with the black colour is key to resolve this issue. Are you sure you are not using a reserved class, or a package name already taken?

Just try with `org.example.helloWorld` and let us know if it still fails.

Comment: @UmarZaii I answered the question, then asked for more information if available. Please read the answer before criticising.

Comment: You should ask him in the comment. `Are you sure you are not using a reserved class, or a package name already taken`. As I said, avoid asking a question in the answer. At all.

Comment: @UmarZaii I know, the thing is that I don't have 50 points yet to comment. Which is something that bothers me from Stackoverflow as I did not want to post an answer, just trying to expand his question ;)